# How to call server side function using jquery wth out page refresh?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

How to call server side function using jquery wth out page refresh?

Answer (score 5):

Use AJAX:

```
$.get('somepage.aspx', {foo: 'bar'}, function(data){
  alert('the page returned this: '+data); 
 });
```

Then set up somepage.aspx to execute the function and return the data (if needed).

For more on jQuery AJAX see this: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could call a custom [ASP.NET PageMethod](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) with jQuery and Microsoft Ajax:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
</head>
<script runat="server">
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom PageMethod that will echo back the argument
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="argument">some arbitrary string</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string MyPageMethod(string argument)
    {
        return "hello " + argument;
    }    
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callPageMthodWithMicrosoftAjax(argument) {
    PageMethods.MyPageMethod(argument, function(result) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
    });
}

function callPageMthodWithjQueryAjax(argument) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/default.aspx/MyPageMethod',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ argument: argument }),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            jQuery('#result').html(data.d);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var jsonError = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            alert(jsonError.Message);
        }

    });
}
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />    
        <a href="#" onclick="callPageMthodWithMicrosoftAjax('Microsoft Ajax')">call PageMethod with Microsoft Ajax</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#" onclick="callPageMthodWithjQueryAjax('jQuery')">call PageMethod with jQuery</a>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you mix getElementById and such with jQuery?

Comment: Good point @Pim, it was copy paste from the callPageMthodWithMicrosoftAjax method in which it is supposed jQuery is not used. I modified my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

if you have server-only methods that you need to call, use a WebMethod on the server side, and ajax on the client.
reading [this](http://www.dev102.com/2008/04/30/call-aspnet-webmethod-from-jquery/) my be useful.

bye

Comment: Doesn't have to be a webservice / webmethod simple jQuery $.get

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you are using asp.net, so you have several options:

1. To get any resource other than the current aspx page, use $.get().  This could be an image file or the output from another aspx page.
2. If you need to round trip your current page and make use of security for you current page, etc. then you can [call a web method](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).  Note that your ViewState will not be available during your call to the web method.  The article I linked to is from Dave Ward's [Encosia](http://www.encosia.com) and he has an extensive series on making AJAX calls with jQuery and Asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jquery .ajax() method.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.aspx/method",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```