# Call ASP.NET function with parameter from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function

I can call a ASP.NET function without parameter from jQuery like following
(default.aspx.cs)

```
public string GetaString()
        {
            return "New String";
        }
```

**jQuery** (default.aspx)

```
$(function () {var returnStr = '<%=GetaString() %>'; };
```

But when calling a function with a parameter I don't get any value.

```
public string GetaString(string str1)
        {
            return "New String"+ str1;
        }

$(function () {var Company = "test";var returnStr = '<%=GetaString(Company) %>'; };
```

Sorry for Miss-information. But its the problem when passing through jquery variable.

How can I pass the parameter to the asp.net function and get return value.
UPDATE
Actual Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#txtCompany").focusout(function () {

            var Company = $("#txtCompany").val();
            var returnStr = '<%=GetNameString("Company") %>';
            var availableTags = returnStr.split('|');
            $("#txtName").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });

        });
});
```

I am filling the autocomplete of txtName from The value in txtCompany.
It works when giving direct parameter.

Comment: The function in the snippet and the one you are calling have different names. Is it the actual code you have posted?

Comment: Please have a look at [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400719/Calling-Server-Side-function-from-Client-Side-Scri)

Comment: oh my bad, i renamed the function name but forgot the name in the jquery

Comment: thanks humpty, but isn't that a preety large code for my problem? Can't we do as simply like in in    
$(function () {var returnStr = '<%=GetaString() %>'; };

Comment: Just reproduced the code locally, everything works as expected.

Comment: andrei can you help with this?
$(function () {var str1="some value"; var returnStr = '<%=GetaString(str1) %>'; }; It says "The name 'str1' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: See my comment to the answer below. This code simply cannot work. However the one you are using should work properly.

Comment: Hmm. Ok then, Need to go with shaz and humpty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using `<%= %>` is a shortcut to the call of `Response.Write` function during the page rendering - check out this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info. Please note that this is the *server-side* part, it actually writes the output to the rendered HTML *before* it is sent to the client. In your first scenario:

```
var returnStr = '<%=GetNameString("Company") %>';
```

page rendering comes to the `<%= %>` part, calls the function `GetNameString` with the argument `"Company"` and writes its output to the page. Then generated markup is sent to the client.

So eventually when the page reaches the client-side, it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#txtCompany").focusout(function () {

            var Company = $("#txtCompany").val();
            var returnStr = 'New StringCompany'; // or whatever the output of the GetNameString is
            var availableTags = returnStr.split('|');
            $("#txtName").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });

        });
});
```

Now the javascript is executed. Clearly it has no notion about server-side functions, just a string literal instead.

If you really want to call server-side function from client-side code, you should do what the others suggested here - implement HttpHandler, web service or page method and make an Ajax call to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some value to the server side, the parameter name should be same. In your case you can try something like this

```
    $(function () {var str1="some value"; var returnStr = '<%=GetaString(str1) %>'; };
```

other codes are same. I assume you have code that actually work to call the server side function.

Comment: It doesnt works :/ The name 'str1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I just gave you pseudo code based on your provided information. If you want the exact code solution,please  provide more information of your actual code so we can really help you. Because your provided code will not be able to call the server side function In my opinion.

Comment: Serajul, sorry but I think this code will never work. `str1` variable is defined in javascript on _client-side_, while the scriplet Ruchan is using is executed on the _server-side_, before any code even reach the client. `GetaString(str1)` won't even compile.

Comment: Actually I got my question wrong a bit. When i send the parameter value directly, it works, but with a variable it shows the error.

Comment: @Ruchan, update the question with the actual code, and we'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ruchan ,
your code is fine , no problems are there 

i just run the code on my pc and its return the "New String Test"   value 
please have below what i run and its return correct value so let me know what exactly you want ?




<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script>

        var returnStr = '<%=GetaString("Test") %>';

        alert(returnStr);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call server side function from Jquery like that. passing the parameter problem comes after that.

you can't call server side function in Jquery like this

```
 $(function () {var returnStr = '<%=GetCompString("Test") %>'; };
```

**Solution**

1. if you have server-only methods that you need to call, use a WebMethod on the server side, and ajax on the client. see [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Ajax&redirect=no)

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MessagePopup.asmx/SendMessage",
    data: "{subject:'" + subject + "',message:'" + message + " pupilId +"'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
      // Do something interesting here.
   }
     });
2. To call ASP.NET AJAX "ScriptServices" and page methods, you need to use the full $.ajax() syntax: [link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
3. see this post

   [How to call server side function using jquery wth out page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814581/how-to-call-server-side-function-using-jquery-wth-out-page-refresh)

Comment: Shaz we actually can call it like that, I have been using it. Just that I cant send parameter as variable.